# Rad Server - Return high number of records

Tags: json, rest, delphi, paging

I am planing to build a Rad server(Rest) project and have some question that I couldn't find an answer. 
Is there a way to send records to the client as paged by using EMS components if I have millions of record in a table. 
if not in this case which methods can be used?

Edit: there is a table with millions of records and user is going to filter and query the records. Is there a way like paging records in Rad Server if User didn't do a good filtering and query returns more records than expected?

Comment: I wonder what client application you are working on that actually needs millions of records in one query.

Comment: I did not say that. I am saying that there is a table with millions of records and user is going to filter and query the records. Is there a way like paging records in Rad Server if User didn't do a good filtering and query returns more records than expected?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but I guess that keeping things back for a specific client to deliver it on later request somehow contradicts the REST principles.

Comment: @UweRaabe 'hello server, please give me record 1001 to 2000 of the query results for this SQL statement ...' is fine with REST, only a bit resource-consuming without server-side caching of the result set, and not very reliable if data is changing...

Comment: @mjn42, of course it is possible to give different requests to achieve that result. I just doubt that there is a built-in solution to have the same with only one wrongly designed query.